# How create variable from file in requst body in Postman

Tags: postman, web-api-testing

I have a file, which I want to send to a server from the postman.

I put the file into request body manually, but I want to use it in all of my requests.

Is it possible to create a variable, which will take a file from my computer and put it to request body?

Comment: Without declaring this as an answer or being downvoted for supplying a link and not the solution, you might want to look at Danny Dainton's excellent guide to Postman... https://github.com/DannyDainton/All-Things-Postman

Comment: Thanks for sharing Chris, I don't have something for this scenario yet. I'm not sure that you could achieve this through the UI in a clean way, have you tried looking at Newman and creating a small script to do this?